# Vaadin Fusion Styling of Sub-Components

Tags: vaadin20, vaadin-fusion, hilla

How do I apply part styling to a nested Vaadin component? Vaadin components expose "parts" for styling in their published APIs.

Specifically, the `vaadin-upload` component hosts another component, `vaadin-upload-file`. I can style the main vaadin-upload component alright, but how do I reach the parts of the nested vaadin-upload-file component?

E.g. for the "name" part of `vaadin-upload-file` I unsuccessfully tried CSS selectors like

```
[part="name"]  { ... // plain, as if it were passed through
vaadin-upload-file[part="name"]  { ... // qualified with the component name
[part="file-list"][part="name"] { ... // qualified by the part of vaadin-upload that hosts the file list
:host([part="file-list"]) [part="name"] { ... // same with :host() selector
```

This is all in the style of the component that deploys `vaadin-upload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer made its way to me on a different path, here is the solution for SO:

You can only apply styles to Vaadin components and their sub-components using a **[custom theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/v20/ds/customization/custom-theme-configuration)**.

Here is a slightly extended way to set this up using a parent theme.

- Create a local custom theme in your app

  - path is `frontend/themes/<my-theme-name>/`
  - must contain a sub-directory `components` (to style Vaadin components)
  - must contain a `styles.css` (even empty)
  - must contain a `theme.json` with contents

    ```
    {
       "parent": "<my-parent-theme>"
    }
    ```

    but there are other keys for theme.json like `importCss`, `documentCss` or `assets`
  - the parent theme can be a pom dependency
- Use the custom theme in your **Application.java**:

  ```
  @Theme(value = "<my-theme-name>")
  public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer ...
  ```
- Then you can add style files locally to style Vaadin components, e.g.

  - add `frontend/themes/<my-theme-name>/components/vaadin-upload.css`:

    ```
    [part=file-list]::before {
      content: "These are the current files:";
    }
    ```
  - `frontend/themes/<my-theme-name>/components/vaadin-upload-file.css`:

    ```
    [part=name] {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    ```

This applies to Vaadin21 (e.g. in Vaadin19 using a parent theme is not working this way).